# Comparing diagnostic test in different populations

Tags: sensitivity-specificity, mcnemar-test

I have 5 diagnostic tests (test A, B, C and D) for a certain disease, tested in 2 different populations.

For comparing test parameters (sensitivity, specificity) of test A and B in the same population I would use a McNemar test, but I do not know how to compare the same test between two different populations. Could be a Chi-Square statistic the correct approach?

Comment: Each test is done in a different population?  What about these two tests are you comparing?

Comment: Tests are diagnostic tests for a dichotomic outcome (disease vs no disease)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE:** the following solution is written based on the first version of the question where there was only two populations and two kinds of tests. But the approach holds for any other number of populations and tests.

Suppose $y$ is your response variable of whether the diagnosis is correct or not (so a binary variable). Then you can use a logistic regression model as:

$$y_{i} \sim Bernoulli(p_{k[i],j[i]})$$

where $p_{k,j}$ is the probability of correct diagnosis in population $k$ (k=1,2) and for test $j$ (j = A, B). So in total you will have four different probabilities of correct diagnosis for each combination of $Population \times Test$. Then you can compare these probabilities. I'll show how this simple model can be fit in R both in a frequentist way using the glm() function and also in a Bayesian way using the R2jags package.

First, **the glm approach:**

```
library(boot) # Package contains the logit transform

# ------ Simulating some data

# synthetic successful diagnosis rates for each combination
pop1_testA = 0.8
pop2_testA = 0.75
pop1_testB = 0.3
pop2_testB = 0.25

set.seed(123)
df = data.frame(population = c(rep("1",500) ,rep("2",500)),
                test = as.factor(c(rep('A',250),rep('B',250),rep('A',250),rep('B',250))),
                correct_diagnosis = c(rbernoulli(250, p = pop1_testA), 
                                      rbernoulli(250, p = pop1_testB),
                                      rbernoulli(250, p = pop2_testA),
                                      rbernoulli(250, p = pop2_testB)))

glm.fit = glm(correct_diagnosis ~ population*test -population -test - 1, data = df, family = binomial(link = 'logit'))
summary(glm.fit)
inv.logit(coef(glm.fit)) # To see the values in the original scale
```

And here are the results:

```
> summary(glm.fit)

Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
population1:testA   1.6883     0.1743   9.686  < 2e-16 ***
population2:testA   1.2196     0.1507   8.091 5.94e-16 ***
population1:testB  -0.8664     0.1385  -6.254 4.01e-10 ***
population2:testB  -1.2425     0.1517  -8.191 2.60e-16 ***

> inv.logit(coef(glm.fit))
population1:testA population2:testA population1:testB population2:testB 
            0.844             0.772             0.296             0.224
```

Now let's fit the model in a **Bayesian way using R2jags.**

```
library(R2jags)

model_code <- "
model
{
  # Likelihood
  for (i in 1:length(y)) {
    y[i] ~ dbin(p[pop[i], test[i]], 1) 
  }
  # Priors
  for (k in 1:max(pop)){
    for(j in 1:max(test)){
    
      p[k,j] ~ dunif(0,1)
    
    }
  }

}
"

# Set up the data
model_data <- list(y = as.numeric(df$correct_diagnosis), pop = as.numeric(df$population), test = as.numeric(df$test))


# Choose the parameters to watch
model_parameters <- c('p')

# Run the model
model_run <- jags(
  data = model_data,
  parameters.to.save = model_parameters,
  model.file = textConnection(model_code))
```

Results of the Bayesian model:

```
> print(model_run)

          mu.vect sd.vect     2.5%      25%      50%      75%    97.5%  Rhat n.eff
p[1,1]      0.791   0.026    0.739    0.773    0.792    0.808    0.840 1.001  2800
p[2,1]      0.727   0.026    0.675    0.709    0.727    0.745    0.778 1.001  2700
p[1,2]      0.317   0.029    0.261    0.297    0.317    0.336    0.375 1.002  1500
p[2,2]      0.270   0.029    0.214    0.249    0.269    0.290    0.328 1.001  3000
```

An important perk of the Bayesian approach that you don't get using the frequentist approach is that now you can calculate probabilities of each of the rates being greater than the other one (and other probabilities like being greater than zero and etc). For example, let's calculate the probability of the test A being more effective in population A than in population B:

$$\pi_{1,1} = P(correct \ diagnosis | pop = 1, test = A)$$
$$\pi_{2,1} = P(correct \ diagnosis | pop = 2, test = A)$$
$$P(\pi_{1,1} > \pi_{2,1}) = ?$$

This is how you can simply calculate the probability in question using the posterior samples of the Bayesian model:

```
probs = model_run$BUGSoutput$sims.list$p

mean(probs[,1,1] > probs[,2,1])
[1] 0.9573333
```

And the answer is roughly 96%.

Comment: Although in the text I just specified two tests, I have 5 different tests, and my idea was performing pairwise comparisons. Nevertheless, your approach is better I was wondering if your code could be adaptable to the approach. In my example, the patients of population A are tested with the tests A, B, C, D, E (so there are repeated measures) (maybe using linear mixed models?)

Comment: It doesn't matter. I have just added a note on top of my solution. You can still use the same approach to solve your problem. Just take the code and apply it with your own data with any number of populations or tests, the code should work fine.